# Having+verb3 in different tenses

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, american-english, spoken-english

I believe the below statements are correct, please provide your inputs if I am wrong.

> 1. Having done the work, I **went** to home.
> 2. Having done the work, I **will go** home.
> 3. Having done the work, I **am going** home.
> 4. Having done the work, I **go** home.

In the above sentences only tense is changed but my question is that ‘Having done’ can be used in all those tenses right?

Answer (score 1):

> ✘ 1. Having done the work, I <del>went to home</del>.
>
> ✓  . Having done the work, **I went** home.
>
> ✓ 2. Having done the work, **I will go** home.
>
> ✓ 3. Having done the work, **I am going** home.
>
> ✘ 4. Having done the work, <del>I go home</del>.

**Past:**

✓ I **went** home.

✓ I **was** home.

✓ I **have gone** home.

**Present:**

✓ **I am going** home.

✓ **I will go** home.

✓ **I am** home.

.

(Also, don't forget that the word "I" is always capitalized!)

Answer (score 0):

When one action happens before another action, you can use having (done) for the first action.

Having found a hotel, they looked for somewhere to have dinner.
Having finished our work, we went home.

We could also say After –ing.

After finishing our work, we went home.